# Pyspark datafame.limit() and drop_duplicates() giving wrong outputs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using a Azure Databricks cluster.

1. Worker and Driver type: Standard_DS4_v2 Specs: 28.0 GB Memory, 8
   Cores, 1.5 DBU
2. Databricks Runtime version : 6.1 (includes Apache
   Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

I have a pyspark dataframe **ttonag_algnd_prdictn_df1**. this has about 32,000 rows.This dataframe is pulled from DB2 using spark.read(...). I just take 10 rows out of it using **limit** key word.

---

`a = ttonag_algnd_prdictn_df1.limit(10)`

a.show() gives (for readability, i did put the file to a text file and made it all be visible in 1 line)

`TONAG_ALGND_PRDICTN_ID,TONAG_MGT_YR,LINE_SGMT_NBR|TRAK_TYP_CD|BGN_MP_NBR|END_MP_NBR|TRAK_SDTRAK_NBR|ALGND_BGN_MP_NBR|ALGND_END_MP_NBR
1   2017    1   M   165.475 168.351 0       165.475 168.351
1   2018    1   M   165.475 168.351 0       165.475 168.351
1   2019    1   M   165.475 168.351 0       165.475 168.351
2   2016    1   M   395.225 405.698 0       395.225 405.698
2   2017    1   M   395.225 405.698 0       395.225 405.698
2   2018    1   M   395.225 405.698 0       395.225 405.698
2   2019    1   M   395.225 405.698 0       395.225 405.698
3   2016    1   M   412.005 422.198 0       412.005 422.198
3   2017    1   M   412.005 422.198 0       412.005 422.198`

Now I do the following operations.

1. select a subset of columns from **'a'** and drop_duplicates.

`unique_mp_pair_df = a.select("LINE_SGMT_NBR","TRAK_TYP_CD","TRAK_SDTRAK_NBR","ALGND_BGN_MP_NBR","ALGND_END_MP_NBR")`


`unique_mp_pair_df.show()`

`+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|LINE_SGMT_NBR|TRAK_TYP_CD|TRAK_SDTRAK_NBR|ALGND_BGN_MP_NBR|ALGND_END_MP_NBR|
+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|            1|          M|         0     |       165.47500|       168.35100|
|            1|          M|         0     |       165.47500|       168.35100|
|            1|          M|         0     |       165.47500|       168.35100|
|            1|          M|         0     |       165.47500|       168.35100|
|            1|          M|         0     |       395.22500|       405.69800|
|            1|          M|         0     |       395.22500|       405.69800|
|            1|          M|         0     |       395.22500|       405.69800|
|            1|          M|         0     |       395.22500|       405.69800|
|            1|          M|         0     |       412.00500|       422.19800|
|            1|          M|         0     |       412.00500|       422.19800|
+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+`

`unique_mp_pair_df = unique_mp_pair_df.drop_duplicates()`

Now i will expect the rows to be unique. However the value i get does not make sense at all.

`unique_mp_pair_df.show()`

`+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|LINE_SGMT_NBR|TRAK_TYP_CD|TRAK_SDTRAK_NBR|ALGND_BGN_MP_NBR|ALGND_END_MP_NBR|
+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|         7101|          M|         0     |        11.29000|        24.88200|
+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+----------------+`

The above is a row in **ttonag_algnd_prdictn_df1** . But after limiting the rows to 10, this was not included. as shown above by doing **a.show()**

Somebody please help me in understanding this. What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? I have followed all the rules. And it is a valid question. Please help me understand the reason it was downvoted.

Comment: Can you check whether predicate pushdown happens for limit(n) records in DB2 connector ?

Comment: what does predicate pushdown mean? and how do i do it?.

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Optimizer-PushDownPredicate.html - more information on predicate pushdown. If possible can you share physical plan of data frame ‘a’ using explain method.

Comment: I used a.cache(). that solved the problem.Thanks for sharing the link. will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to understand the laziness of the execution of spark, and the limit is random.

Your first a.limit().show() and second a.limit().drop_duplicates.show() is two different execution. And because limit is randomly choose 10 rows, so two different show might result into two different results.

Comment: I used a.cache(). that solved the problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: yup, cache persist the data in memory, so avoid reselecting random 10 rows, glad it works